# include file и jQuery load() того же файла

Tags: php, jquery, функции, include

Имеется файл, который подключается через include к главной странице (так он работает). Так-же этот файл взываю аяксом и тут, через if определяю если запрос аякс, то добавляю коннект к базе и функции, и тут проблема:
без инклуда функций ругается, что их нету, а когда включаю то опять ругается:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

```
<?php
$ajax = (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') ? false : true;
if ($ajax)
{   
    session_start();
    include('/../../inc/config.php');
    include('/../../inc/functions.php');
    $tpl    = new Template;
    $tpl->dir = "/../../templates/".$_SITE["skin"]."/";
}

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != '') {
    $tpl->load_template('profile_logged.tpl');
} else {
    $tpl->load_template('/../../templates/'.$_SITE['skin'].'/profile_login.tpl');
}

$tpl->compile('user_block');
$tpl->clear();
if ($ajax) echo $tpl->result['user_block'];
$tpl->clear();
?>
```

Вот и сам js:

```
$("#logout").click(function() {
$("#logout" ).load( "/modules/profil/logout.php");
$("#mini-profile" ).load( "/modules/profil/auth_page.php"); 
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте `require_once('/../../inc/functions.php')`, проверьте `class_exists`.
А вообще, такие ошибки появляются при одинаковых именах функций в одном классе.

Comment: class_exists помогло